# Execute function at soft key enter

Tags: android, keylistener

I'm trying to add a way to execute a function on a soft key enter (or whatever the bottom right hand key would be, I assume its usually a enter/done key) once a edit text field has been filled in with numbers. I also have a calculate button that I would like to keep as a back up in an attempt to 'idiot proof' the app a little bit. below is a snippet of my code thus far; this part is working:

1. `onCalculate` refers to a button I have.
2. I have error checking for null values and whatever else.

   EditText something

   public void onCalculate (View v){

   do stuff....
   }

I want to add something down here to 'do stuff' in the event the user presses the done/enter/bottom right hand soft key instead of pressing the button. Below is a snippet from my layout XML:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_margin/>
```

I know I probably need to create some kind of key listener for the enter key, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by associating an `OnEditorActionListener` to the EditText. For example:

```
editText1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
editText1.setOnEditorActionListener(new new OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        {
            onCalculate(editText1);
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so am I essentially wrapping the 'listener' part of the code (above) around my already existing code that executes when the calculate button is pressed?

Comment: You add this code (for example in `onCreateView()`) to setup an `OnEditorActionListener`. This listener should call your previous "calculate" method (as in the example I provided), and that's it.